# Expanding array from UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift3

I am trying to expand my array, which I have saved in UserDefaults. I have 2 views, in the first view I declare array with 3 subject and then I saved it in UserDefaults. In the second view I can print them, but when I am trying to expand my array with new subject from UITextView, i get error message

Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

What am i doing wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!

var array: [String] = ["Prvni", "Druhy"]
var prvni = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func zapsat(_ sender: UIButton) {

    prvni = text.text!
    array.insert(prvni, at: 2)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.setValue(array, forKey: "KEY")

    defaults.synchronize()
}


@IBAction func vypsat(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY")) != nil){
        let historyWords = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY") as? [String])!
        print(historyWords)
    }
}
```

}

and the second viewcontroller

```
class druhy: UIViewController {

var array = [String]()
var druhy = ""
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func vypsat(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY")) != nil){
        let historyWords = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY") as? [String])!
        print(historyWords)
    }
}

@IBAction func zapsat(_ sender: UIButton) {

    druhy = text.text!
    if((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY")) != nil){
        var array = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY") as? [String])!
        print(array)
    }
    array.insert(druhy, at: 3)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.setValue(array, forKey: "KEY")

    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `var` declaration from your array in this code to use your global array

```
var array = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY") as? [String])!
```

to

```
array = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY") as? [String])!
```

then instead of insert, use append

```
array.append(druhy)
```

So total code -

```
druhy = text.text!
    if((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY")) != nil){
        array = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "KEY") as? [String])!
        print(array)
    }
    array.append(druhy,)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.setValue(array, forKey: "KEY")

    defaults.synchronize()
```